# Should Cocos2d be used or create own code in C

Tags: c++, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am starting to design a platform style game using xcode, that will need to use some physics, collision detection etc. including obstacles like rolling rocks, ropes etc.

Should I use Cocos2d/box2d for my project or create my own code?

The reason I am unsure is for a couple of reasons (some have already been answered in other posts)
1. Ive never used Cocos or box2d and not sure how to integrate this into my game (but im sure I will figure this out quicker than building a custom engine?!)

1. The main reason: Is I want to also convent this game to Android. With my own code I would be able to do this, but using 3rd party code, wouldnt this be near impossible and I would have to design the engine anyway for android?

On a side note, if anyone has any great links to cocos2d tutorials how to use the engine in a project, that would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With all respect, judging by your questions and comments (ie you asked if cocos2d is comparable to box2d) you should focus entirely on writing your app. Don't try to make a game engine, don't try to even think about cross-platform development. Both are much, much more work than you seem to be aware of. Also, read this: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/05/the-game-engine-dating-guide-how-to-find-the-right-engine-for-your-game/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The main reason: Is I want to also convent this game to Android. With
>   my own code I would be able to do this, but using 3rd party code,
>   wouldnt this be near impossible and I would have to design the engine
>   anyway for android?

You can use [Cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/). It's a `C++` porting of Cocos2d and supports several platforms, including Android.

Comment: Thanks, and is Cocos any better than box2d? Or are they both similar? Thanks

Comment: They are different libs. Cocos is a 2d graphics library meanwhile Box2d is a physics library.

Comment: Oh right, So I assume I will be better with Box2D, as it is the physics I am after.

Comment: Unless you have written a cross platform 2d graphic engine, I'd go with cocos2dx for the graphic too.